# Setting frame value for all items in IBOutletCollection

Tags: ios, swift, frame, uiviewanimation, cgrectmake

I created an IBOutletCollection with some UIElements (Label, Button, TextField) that i would like to move on a special event.

thats what I have so far:

```
@IBAction func moveDown(sender: UIButton) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: {
            for subview in self.moveOutViews {
                var offset = CGFloat(700);
                var newY = subview.frame.origin.y + offset;
                subview.frame = CGRectMake(subview.frame.origin.x, newY, subview.frame.size.width, subview.frame.size.height);
            }
            }, completion: {
                (value: Bool) in
                UIView.commitAnimations();

        });
}
```

now my problem is, when the Animation is completed, and i want to interact with the UIElements (TextField) on the new position, all views '**jump**' back to the origin position.

maby it's a problem that the '**sender**' is part of the **IBOutletCollection**?

It's an iPad for iOS 8.3 app and i am using Swift.

**Edit:** I made a workaround with an UIScrollView. But I would like to know why the first idea isn't working.

Comment: The problem is probably that you have constraints that are setting the item's position and once those constraints are re-applied then your manual change to the frame is overridden.  If you set an IBOutlet for the first item's Y position constraint and then set all of the other item's Y position to be in alignment with the first object then all you need to do is modify the constant of the constraint IBOutlet and call setNeedsLayout

Comment: I don't have constraints. 

I have tried your idea but still the same issue.

Comment: Why are you calling `UIView.commitAnimations()` in the completion block?  That call is unnecessary with block-based animation

Answer (score 0):

Since we don't know how your view is setup I will have to guess that it is one of two things:

1. Like @Paulw11 suggested in his comment. You are editing the frames of views that are held by constraints. When the view is laid out again all views snap back to positions determined by the constraints. Event though you say that you are not using constraints it is possible that `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` is enabled for your views or that your xib/storyboard is set to use constraints and so constraints are automatically generated for you. One way to check this is to just log the `constraints` property of a subview.
2. You have code somewhere else in your app that is changing the position of your views and it is inadvertently being called.

Comment: How can i show you the view's setup?
To point 1: the log shows only `(Function)`

To point 2: definitely no.

Comment: If you are using storyboard/xib you can't show it. If that is the case check if "Use Auto Layout" is checked in `Utilities panel (right side) > File Inspector > Interface Builder Document` of your storyboard/xib. Otherwise just post a sample of the code you are using to create your views.

Comment: Yes i'm using a xib for that view. Use Auto Layout is checked.

Comment: Then your problem is stated in 1. Either uncheck `Use Auto Layout` so you are using springs and struts or animate the constraints.